# Using gestures to move from one view to another in tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, xcode

So i have an app in which i use starboard. My main navigation is done by tab bar controller. Now i want to be able to switch multiple views in one tab. I know how to do this with navigation controller and buttons, but cant figure it out how to use gestures for it ... 
My build looks like these:

```
    tabbar controlller ->view controller ->some view
    //here i want to use gestures
    tabbar controlller ->view controller->view one->view two
```

So i want to be able to make gesture and move from view one to view two.

I know i/m newmbie but i tryied really hard to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried?  Did you set up a gesture recognizer and upon recognizing the gesture, present  your next view modally?  Seems straight forward...

Try this setup:

Your view that recognizes the gesture:
rootViewController-->tabBarController-->ViewControllerWithGestureRecognizer

When the gesture is recognized, pop the tabbarController and load your first of two views:
rootViewController-->firstView

That view may have another gesture recognizer, or some way to navigate to your second view or back to the tabbarController...

Comment: Yes i did that and it works just fine when i jsut have 2 views but when i try to set those views into a tabbar controler as 3 item it crashes when i go to thease tab :S

Comment: Ok i managed to solve the problem :s The problem was with the way i was embeding my views... I neede to add one more view and set segue it to my swithing views.

Comment: Well it doesnt work if i do that way u suggested. My rootView is tab bar. And when i try to use gestures to get back to my tabbar it doesn/t work either just nothing happens :S I'm gonna get u a picture of my setup...

Comment: You have a navigation controller, so it should be easier.  Just use the navigation controller to push/pop to the appropriate views.  Is it the gesture recognizer that's not working?